# Replace everything but number and >actual< decimal points

Tags: regex, replace

I'm trying to get a regex working that will replace everything except for numbers and a decimal point (easy). The tricky part: the decimal point is optional but, if present, must be trailed by a further number.

So:

```
.10 => 10
10. => 10
10.- => 10
1.0 => 1.0
```

I'm not quite sure how to define the "except numbers followed by an optional decimal point but mandatory number after the optional decimal point" bit :)

Thanks!

Comment: Regexes are _fun!_ But I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. For starters, you need to learn which characters are special: _"metacharacters"_ which need to be escaped (i.e. with a backslash placed in front - and the rules are different inside and outside character classes.) There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regex is actually not new to me at all, I'm usually quite comfortable with regex but I've gotten rusty and I always have trouble with negated patterns for replace statements. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

(Please note that the regex syntax you are using may require different escaping.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with JavaScript and I tried this: `string.replace(/[^\d+(\.\d+)]?/g, '');` - which isn't working. 20.00. will result in 20.00. - Sorry, I always have trouble understanding negated patterns.

Comment: No no, square brackets can't be used like that! They are only for classes of characters, e.g. `[abc]` matches one of `a`, `b`, `c` and `[^abc]` matches any character which is not `a`, `b` or `c`, but you can't use that for negating the entire match. You have to do it differently. You have to collect all the numbers (not using `replace` but `match` or something like that) and then create a new string concatenating those. That's the result you are after.

Comment: I thought I could replace it directly. Extracting the match and discarding the rest works. Thank you!